# Class 'Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable' not found

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable, infyom

I'm using laravel infyOm generator and I added a model from its GUI with a tick on the data table section.

My php version is 7.3.10 and my laravel version is 8.12 and the InfyOm generator version is also 8.

InfyOm generator works perfectly without this data table error. when I trying to view my added model from UI it shows this error.

Can someone please give me a solution for this, I tried the GitHub issue answers, but not worked for my situation.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried to have a better look at the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if you have the dependency installed

Installing the package

https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/installation#installing-laravel-datatables